# Bootstrap: Trouble With Responsive Centered Columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I'm having trouble aligning `<h2>` in a straight line on a Bootstrap page (centered column) as shown in the snippet below.

```css
h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default {
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    opacity: 100%;
}

.row-footer{
    background-color: #AfAfAf;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.icons {
 display: inline;
}

/* centered columns styles */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Responsive Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-social.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ALOK</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-centered">
            <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Pizza</li>
            <li>Crab</li>
            <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-centered">
            <h2>Achievements</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-centered">
            <h2>More About Me</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-footer">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="icons" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">Â© Copyright 2016 Alok's Webpage!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I add the `<ul>` after `<h2>` the remaining `<h2>` gets misaligned. [I have shown the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nvmP.png) How do I align them?

Comment: use min-height to your 3 divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done and worked perfectly check it. Hope this works for you.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  border-color: #E7E7E7;
  opacity: 100%;
}
.row-footer {
  background-color: #AfAfAf;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.icons {
  display: inline;
}
/* centered columns styles */

.row-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* reset the text-align */
  text-align: left;
  /* inline-block space fix */
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>ALOK</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4col-centered">
        <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Apples</li>
          <li>Pizza</li>
          <li>Crab</li>
          <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4col-centered">
        <h2>Achievements</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4col-centered">
        <h2>More About Me</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-footer">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
          <h5>Links</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
          <h5>Our Address</h5>
          <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="icons" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
            <p align="center">Â© Copyright 2016 Alok's Webpage!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that should be a  comment

Comment: The middle `<h2>` has gone above. The first and the last `<h2>` has gone below. They are still not on a straight line. I have attached another picture.

Comment: I want the remaining `<h2>` to appear just like the first `<h2>` all in the same row and in a straight line.

Comment: check it i have make the changes.

Comment: This is even better. Thanks a Million.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried to add three columns in a row for small screen, it was break.
Add proper classes for columns. `col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-centered`

```css
  
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    opacity: 100%;
}

.row-footer{
    background-color: #AfAfAf;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.icons {
  display: inline;
}

/* centered columns styles */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none !important;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Responsive Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-social.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ALOK</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-centered">
            <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Pizza</li>
            <li>Crab</li>
            <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-centered">
            <h2>Achievements</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-centered">
            <h2>More About Me</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-footer">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="icons" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">Â© Copyright 2016 Alok's Webpage!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a min-height to your h2 div's min-height:200px;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Responsive Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-social.css">
  <style type="text/css"> 
    h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
    opacity: 100%;
}

.row-footer{
    background-color: #AfAfAf;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.icons {
  display: inline;
}

/* centered columns styles */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
 
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>ALOK</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>



   <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="min-height:200px;">
            <h2>Favorite Foods</h2>
            <ul>
            <li>Apples</li>
            <li>Pizza</li>
            <li>Crab</li>
            <li>Chocolate Cake</li>
        </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="min-height:200px;">
            <h2>Achievements</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4" style="min-height:200px;">
            <h2>More About Me</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-footer">             
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                  121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                  Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                  HONG KONG<br>
                  Tel.: +852 1234 5678<br>
                  Fax: +852 8765 4321<br>
                  Email: <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
               </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="icons" style="padding: 40px 10px;">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p style="padding:10px;"></p>
                    <p align="center">Â© Copyright 2016 Alok's Webpage!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```